# Conjecture over an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, closed-form

So, integral question time.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)e^{-x}\ \text{d}x$$

I was trying to compute this integral, and at a certain point I checked with Mathematica, and it solved it in a numerical way, returning the following result:

$$1.4721301560626(...)$$

I am now asking if there is a way to obtain this result in a close form. I found out that that number can be expressed as

$$\frac{1}{8}\left(60 C - 4 - 21\pi +\pi^2 + 68\pi \ln(2) - 38\pi \ln(3)\right)$$

Where $C$ is the Catalan constant.

But even better as

$$\frac{1097113}{2341289}\pi$$

Despite those forms are not exact.

Is there a way to solve that integral in order to get the result in a close form?

I am not saying I strongly think there must be a close form, but it would be nice!

Comment: May be $\frac{4394963645713}{2985445021701}$ could be a better approximation (at least 25 decimal places). I really wonder how it could be done in a closed form. My computer and CAS's gave up ! Cheers.

Comment: On the left side of the interval (in the limit $x \longrightarrow 0$) the integrand looks like $2xe^{-x}$.  Wondering if this is of some use.

Comment: Since you have Mathematica, you could try this: http://math.hawaii.edu/~dale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html. It conjectures multiple closed forms and ranks them based on plausibility.

Comment: IMHO there is no interesting closed form for this. Maybe if you change the bound 1 for $+\infty$  things are better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $k\geq 1$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x)\, x^{k-1} \,dx = -\frac{H_k}{k},\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x^2)\, x^{k-1} \,dx = -\frac{H_{k/2}}{k} \tag{A}$$
hence it follows that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)e^{-x}\,\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}+\!\!\!\!\!\!\underbrace{\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\cdot \frac{2H_k-H_{k/2}}{k}}_{\text{fast-convergent and with alternating signs}}\tag{B}$$

and plenty of accurate approximations are simple to derive. On the other hand, I would not bet on the existence of a simple closed form for the highlighted series, if not in terms of exponential integrals.

Comment: Amazing! I always learn something from you!